Unable to expose portainer via url using traefik
I deployed portainer on a VM in docker swarm mode and I could access it via ip address and port.
I then deloyed traefik from the portainer UI and some other apps which I was able to successfully expose via traefik using their URLS (installed the certs and so on in the correct paths for traefik to use on the VM)
Everything is working fine with my apps but I also want portainer to be accessible via URL. It uses the same wildcard domain name as my other apps.
On the portainer UI I edited the portainer_portainer service configuration to inclue below labels
      labels:
        # Frontend
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`portainer.mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.service=frontend"
        # Edge
        - "traefik.http.routers.edge.rule=Host(`edge.mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.edge.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.services.edge.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
        - "traefik.http.routers.edge.service=edge"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "8000:8000"
      - "9443:9443"

Networks look like this
networks:
  public:
    external: true
  agent_network:
    external: true

When I try and get to my portainer URL it resolves but I get Gateway Timeout on a blank white webpage.
If I access it without https I get the page loading if I ignore but theres a warning saying there is no cert
Routing via IP and port 9443 still works.
On my traefik UI I can see portainer service there and I see no errors on the routing .
My traefik config looks like this. Path to certs are same for portainer and other applications as its a wildcard
version: '3.2'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    environment:
      ACME_DNS_API_BASE: https://auth.acme-dns.io
      ACME_DNS_STORAGE_PATH: /acme-dns.json
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=leresolver
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].main=mydomain.com
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].sans=*mydomain.com
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.swarm.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=public
      - --api=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.email=me@mydomain.com
      - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=/acme.json
      - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.keyType=EC384
      - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.dnsChallenge=true
      - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=acme-dns
      - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.dnsChallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,8.8.8.8:53
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - public
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /obtools-drive/traefik_data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - /obtools-drive/traefik_data/acme-dns.json:/acme-dns.json

    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.role == manager ]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        #dashboard
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=dashboard@internal"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        #api
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        #general
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$2y$$05$$q0t44et4tg4ete4t4t4tUufaziferwerw"

networks:
  public:
    external: true


I had not added portainer to the public network , it was just part of ingress network and agent-portainer network. When I added to public network it became accessible
